# Google App Scripts (Sheets) not connecting YouTube brand account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**The problem:**

I've been stuck trying to figure this out all day. I'm writing an app script within my Google Sheets to query YouTube API data from a particular YouTube channel, and it works when I connect every account but the actual YouTube account (brand account) we're trying to query.

**The setup:**

youtube.email@gmail.com - where the YouTube account is hosted.
ryan@gSuiteCo.com - where I am writing the script.

**What happens:**

When I execute my code, it asks for authorization, so I log in with youtube.email@gmail.com. Then it gives me the option to choose the YouTube Brand account or the youtube.email@gmail.com Google account. If I select the email Google account it works (but then is pulling from the wrong YT account). If I select my YouTube account, nothing works, and I end up in an authorization loop. I hit run, and a pop-up asks me to authorize. After authorized, it doesn't actually run... and that's an infinite loop.

My suspicion is that the issue relates to enabling YouTube API. For every account, I am able to login to the admin and enable the APIs for my App Script, but I have no way of doing that for the YouTube account. When I enable it for youtube.email@gmail.com, it enables it for the wrong YouTube brand account.

So, I have no idea what's going on. What's the right way to do this? I have tried just writing and deploying the code from the youtube.email@gmail.com account, and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's because of [a known Apps Script issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374) where it has trouble working when you are logging into multiple Google Accounts - it always uses the default account.

Romain Vialard recently [wrote an article](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/multiple-accounts-issue-with-google-apps-script) about how they get around the issue.

Comment: I actually log out of all accounts and only log in to the the one gmail account associated with the YouTube brand, and it still gives me this issue.

Comment: Did u guys figure out a good work-around, @Andrew Roberts, @ryangineer? 3 years later I am having the same problem. I only log in with one Gmail account. However, the Youtube channel is a BRAND CHANNEL managed by this Gmail account, not the personal Youtube channel of this Gmail account. I am still stuck in an indefinite loop exactly as described.